# Перебор массива в js

Tags: javascript

Не пойму почему не прорабатывает как нужно функция в js:

```js
let teams = [{
          Name: 'Vasa',
          Age: 25
        },{
          Name: 'Alex',
          Age: 20
        },{
          Name: 'Mark',
          Age: 20
        }]
          
   
    function filterCountry(object,key) {
    var arr1 = [];
      key.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        
        var result = object.filter(team => team.Age === item)
        arr1.push(result[0]);
        
      });

     return arr1;
    }
    
    var result1 = filterCountry(teams, [25,20]);
    
    console.log(result1);
```

Почему функция .filter выбирает лишь один элемент, а не два?

Как сделать так, чтобы вывело все правильно?

Ожидаемый рез:

```
result1 = [{
      Name: 'Vasa',
      Age: 25
      },{
      Name: 'Alex',
      Age: 20
      },{
      Name: 'Mark',
      Age: 20
    }]
```

Comment: Потому что Вы для каждого элемента массива `key` добавляете в `arr1` ровно один - первый - элемент из `result`. Соответственно, `filterCountry` у Вас всегда возвращает массив той же длины, что и переданный ей массив `keys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` выбирает два, вы берете только один. `result[0]`.

Как вариант:

```js
let teams = [{
  Name: 'Vasa',
  Age: 25
}, {
  Name: 'Alex',
  Age: 20
}, {
  Name: 'Mark',
  Age: 20
}, {
  Name: 'Clark',
  Age: 22
}]
//----------------------------------------------------------------


function filterCountry(object, key) {
  var arr1 = [];
  key.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {

    var result = object.filter(team => team.Age === item)
    if (result.length == 1)
      arr1.push(result[0]);
    else {
      for (let i of result) {
        arr1.push(i);
      }
    }

  });

  return arr1;
}

var result1 = filterCountry(teams, [25, 20]);

console.log(result1);
```

Comment: А. Точно. Блин. Спасибо за указание ошибки. )

Answer (score 2):

```js
let teams = [{
  Name: 'Vasa',
  Age: 25
}, {
  Name: 'Alex',
  Age: 20
}, {
  Name: 'Mark',
  Age: 20
}]


function filterCountry(object, key) {
  return object.filter(team => key.some(age => team.Age == age));
}
var result1 = filterCountry(teams, [25, 20]);

console.log(result1);
```